# How can i solve this? Theres a problem with AMD configurations

Tags: fglrx

As the title shows up, i tried to installed amdconf but it shows up that command is not found.. How can i solve it then?

Can you help me?

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f but it shows "command not found"!?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

amdconfig appears to be in the fglrx package.  You need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

### Reference:

```
chris@chris-office:~$ apt-file search amdconfig
fglrx: /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdconfig
fglrx-updates: /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/amdconfig
```